# Setting print preferences in my script

Tags: javascript, printing, xul, xulrunner

I'm using HTML template to print bills and paper height is dynamic. I'm using printSilent mode. So no dialog box shows up with the print settings. It's using default template, and when height of bill is greater then the height of A4 size paper, white space(margin) is visible. I want to remove that. Is there a way to set print preferences like paper height and width in my script? I'm using XULRunner for my application.